# Working with string in Ruby on Rails and attempt to simplify the code

Tags: ruby

I wonder if there is any way to simplify the code below. I hope the way exists.

```
def add_meta_tag_keywords
    keyword_meta_tag = ""
    keyword_meta_tag << "#{params[:tag]}" if params[:tag].present?
    if params[:city].present?
      if keyword_meta_tag.present?
        keyword_meta_tag << ", #{params[:city]}"
      else
        keyword_meta_tag << "#{params[:city]}"
      end
    end

    if params[:region].present?
      if keyword_meta_tag.present?
        keyword_meta_tag << ", #{params[:region]}"
      else
        keyword_meta_tag << "#{params[:region]}"
      end
    end

    if keyword_meta_tag.present?
      keyword_meta_tag << "."
      append_meta_tag_keywords keyword_meta_tag
    end
  end
```

What are your ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functional approach:

```
def add_meta_tag_keywords
  fields = params.values_at(:tag, :city, :region).select(&:present?)
  append_meta_tag_keywords(fields.join(", ") + ".") unless fields.empty?
end
```

Comment: Minor detail: should be a space after the comma in the `join`.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall: Indeed, fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Accumulating them in an array first, then joining them together greatly simplifies the logic:

```
def add_meta_tag_keywords
  keyword_meta_tags = []
  keyword_meta_tags << params[:tag]
  keyword_meta_tags << params[:city]
  keyword_meta_tags << params[:region]

  keyword_meta_tags = keyword_meta_tags.reject(&:blank?)
  if keyword_meta_tags.any?
    keyword_meta_tag = keyword_meta_tags.join(', ').concat('.')
    append_meta_tag_keywords keyword_meta_tag
  end
end
```

Comment: It's really an amazing solution.

Comment: Why the imperative `x = []`, `x << 1`, `x << 2`, `x << 3` instead of the simple expression `x = [1, 2, 3]`?

Comment: @tokland Probably because nested `[]`s look noisy to me, and `values_at` didn't come to mind at the time `:)` (+1 on yours).

Comment: @AndrewMarshall: thanks for the +1 :-) I see what you're saying, in that case I'd write a multi-line array so the multiples []'s don't look ugly.